# IOC/DI CastleWindsor returns same instance every time

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

The project am working implements IOC/DI using castle windsor. There are many modules in project. There is a module called `ProcessEngine` that send the `Invoices` to my module for Automatic Process which involves 7 steps.

Up to now `ProcessEngine` module use to send `Invoices` one by one as in a queue and my module worked perfectly. But now `ProcessEngine` send many invoices that are ready by spanning them in different threads each invoice having there own thread so the problem arises.

The problem I  see is that the instances are created by using Castle Windsor and it returns the same object everytime. That means all threads are having same instance and it creates the chaos. Then I created instances of major classes that have some private properties by using **new** keyword and it worked fine.

**Is there any way I can restrict Castle Windsor container to return new instance everytime for some of the classes of my module?** It is Architecture guideline of the project that object must be instantiated using Castle Windsor not using new keyword. Is there any solution for this?

Any help will be highly appericiated. I dont have much knowledge of Castle Windsor but I observed It is kind of Singleton Pattern as it returns same object everytime using Castle Windsor.

Comment: You should consider using paragraphs, not using them makes your question hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check [lifestyles](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx).

Default behaviour is singleton, which means it will indeed return the same instance when you ask for resolve.

You can use PerThread or Transient lifestyle.

Comment: I would not advise usage of Per Thread lifestyle unless someone really knows they need it. It is easily misused.

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic : Yes it is not easy to use indeed, I prefer Transient generally, but in some cases it can be very useful, so it's worth mentioning.